# Deploying application on Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I am trying to run the sample application from RoseIndia:

http://www.roseindia.net/jsf/SimpleHelloByEnteringName.shtml

I downloaded the source code, and put the folder in the webapps folder, as outlined. Do I have to create a .war or .jar from the app and put that somewhere in the webapps folder as well to run the application?

Comment: What happened when you try to access application? Did it throw any exception or get any response code?

Comment: Well, the only thing I have added to the tomcat directory is the project folder in the webapps folder directly. When I run it it with http://localhost:8080/SimpleHelloByEnteringName/ I get a 404, the requested resource is not available. I can get to the manager, so I know the server is up, but from what I know about webapplications, I thought the only thing I needed to deploy to the server was the .ear or .war, not the actual project folder

Comment: anyone have any ideas? the site seems to suggest that I just drop the project folder into webapps and try to navigate to the url, but that's not working

Comment: That's not enough as a vanilla Tomcat doesn't have JSF on board by default, so you need to install JSF - but that's easier said than done, working on it now.

Comment: After some investigation I'd suggest you drop that example and switch to [a better one, like the one here](http://www.coreservlets.com/JSF-Tutorial/jsf2/).  The RoseIndia one is apparently still for JSF1 and doesn't help you in any way wrt runtime requirements, the coreservlets one gives you a starting point project that works out of the box (as it comes with dependencies included).  Btw, it's better to avoid RoseIndia alltogether, read [an opinion](http://balusc.blogspot.be/2008/06/what-is-it-with-roseindia.html) from [a fellow SO user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc)

Comment: Thanks, I actually decided to try it on GlassFish, are you familiar with how to deploy to that server?